# How to change style depend on key in v-for?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to write small app that change style depend on key in `v-for` loop. I can't figure out how to change style.

I want to colorize `one` as blue, `two` as green, `three` as red.

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <template v-for="(v,k) in tableData">
       <tr v-bind:class="background-color: {{k}}">
        {{v}}   
       </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
```

code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tableData: 
     {
      "one": "I am one",
      "two": "I am two",
      "three": "I am three",
     }
  }
})
```

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/pevLgf0b/

it's seems that I should use computed property, but I can't understand how to do it in right way.

Answer (score 2):

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/y295qd04/

you can use method to get different color dynamically

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  <table>
    <template v-for="(v,k) in tableData">
       <tr v-bind:style="style(k)">
        <td>
          {{v}}   
        </td>
       </tr>

    </template>
  </table>

</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tableData: {
      "one": "I am one",
      "two": "I am two",
      "three": "I am three",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    style(k) {
      switch (k) {
        case 'one':
          return {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
          }
        case 'two':
          return {
            backgroundColor: 'green'
          }
        case 'three':
          return {
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
          }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more data object for colors.
https://jsfiddle.net/pevLgf0b/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tableData: 
     {
     "one": "I am one",
      "two": "I am two",
      "three": "I am three",
    },
     colorData:{
      "one" : "blue",
      "two" : "green",
      "three" : "red",
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">

  <table>
    <template v-for="(v,k) in tableData">
       <tr v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': colorData[k] }">
       <td>{{v}}   </td>
       </tr>
      
    </template>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this work perfectly,

I've bind class based on the key. I have created a function which will return appropriate class based on the value and the style is applied.

Try this:

```
<template>
    <table>
      <template v-for="(v,k) in tableData">
        <tr v-bind:class="applyStyle(k)">
          <td>{{v}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: {
        one: "I am one",
        two: "I am two",
        three: "I am three"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    applyStyle(value) {
      if (value == "one") {
        return "applyRed";
      }
      if (value == "two") {
        return "applyGreen";
      }
      if (value == "three") {
        return "applyBlue";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.applyRed {
  background-color: red;
}
.applyGreen {
  background-color: green;
}
.applyBlue {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```